# Issue with archiving files

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-1.0

I am trying to archiving old files in the server (older then 90 days) and it should be separate ZIP file for every month. I have [powershell-v1.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v1.0) so I am not able to use `System.Management.Automation.PSObject`

I have created a script but I have a problem with zip file name. When I run the script all files are moving to one archive with name `+++`.

```
$folders ="C:\New folder\test\"

Function Zip
{
               Param
               (
                              [string]$zipFile
                              ,
                              [string[]]$toBeZipped
               )
               $CurDir = Get-Location
               Set-Location "C:\program files\7-zip\"
               .\7z.exe A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
               Set-Location $CurDir
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders | Where-Object {$_.LastwriteTime -lt ((Get-date).adddays(-90))} | % { $_.FullName};


if ( !$files)

{break}

else 
{

Write-Host $files

   $file_year = $files.LastwriteTime.Year
   $file_month = $files.LastwriteTime.Month


echo  $file_month

  ZIP $folders+"$file_year"+"$file_month"+".zip" $files



If(Test-Path $folders+$file_year+$file_month+.zip)
{
               Remove-Item $files
}}
```

It would be nice if someone can figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues why this doesn't work. First, you are selecting (using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet `%`) the `FullName` property thus won't be able to access the `LastWriteTime` property anymore. Secondly, you are trying to access the property on a potential array of files (which year and month you want to use?)

So I would change / refactor your script to something like this (**untested**).

```
$folders ="C:\New folder\test\"

function Write-ZipFile
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$Path,
        [string[]]$Files
    )
    $7zip = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles '\7-zip\7z.exe'
    & $7zip A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-date).AddDays(-90)) }

$zipFile = Join-Path $folders ('{0}{1}.zip' -f $files[0].LastwriteTime.Year, $files[0].LastwriteTime.Month)

Write-ZipFile -Path $zipFile -Files ($files | select -ExpandProperty FullName)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of file names to archive is in $files. Use `$files.GetType()` to see that it is an array. Use `$files[0].GetType()` to see that each element is a string type, not a file object type.

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders |
    Where-Object {$_.LastwriteTime -lt (Get-date).adddays(-90)}

I imagine that you will want to omit directories.

The $files array will be an array of FileInfo objects, not strings.

Secondly, do something to iterate over the list of FileInfo objects.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$folders = "H:\src\powershell\afm"

Function Zip
{
    Param (
         [string]$zipFile
         , [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )

    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders -File |
    Where-Object {($_.LastwriteTime -lt (Get-date).adddays(-10)) -and ($_.Extension -ne ".zip")}

$files | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose "Working on file $_"

    $file_year = $_.LastwriteTime.Year
    $file_month = $_.LastwriteTime.Month

    Write-Verbose "file_month is $file_month"

    Zip "$folders\$file_year$file_month.zip" "$folders\$_"

    If (Test-Path "$folders\$file_year$file_month.zip")
    {
        ### Remove-Item $_q
    }
}
```

It would appear that the problem is that there is nothing to process each file to archive them. There is no ForEach-Object.

There is no LastWriteTime on an array object, only on a FileInfo object.